# How to connect SSD1309 OLED with STM32 via i2c

Tags: stm32, display, i2c

I have a 1.5 OLED SSD1309 display with ZIF connector. Based on a interfacing scheme from the seller I made a scheme that should connect this display with STM32 based MCU via i2c. Interfacing scheme is based on AT MCU, so I wonder can this apply to any type of MCU?

[image: SSD1309 scheme]

Here is the link I used as a reference: https://www.buydisplay.com/download/interfacing/ER-OLED015-2_Interfacing.pdf (I also don't understand this VCC +12.5V, do I  have to make add 3V to 12.5V regulator based circuit as well?)

I also found this: https://github.com/afiskon/stm32-ssd1306
It says that this library is working with SSD1309 as well, so I would use it for this if all this above make sense and can work.

Does someone have experience with this type of connecting OLED displays with MCU, because almost all I could find are already soldered boards with display on it.

---

Comment: Yes, the i2c bus is pretty much a standard. I believe that 12.5v is a power for backlight or so.

Comment: Why does it need backlight if it's OLED display? Not really sure do I have to implement this 12.5V to the circuit, or I can just connect that pin to 3.3V as well

Comment: It maybe something else. I have SSD1306 based display and it works from +3.3v. I don't see any pin for high voltage like 12.5v there.

Comment: Yes, I know you don't really need those 12.5V. Just want to be sure that this scheme I made will work once I connect it with STM32 MCU